# how to call h files in c++ project

Tags: c++

first i created a folder name 'C:MyProject' and then another 2 folders inside the 'MyProject' have created called 'src' and 'include'.After that i opened a new project in c++ and saved it in the 'MyProject' as myproject.dev. then i added 2 folders to my project for that i used same name which i created in my project folder('src','include'). then two headear files i added to the project name a.hpp and b.hpp (inside include folder) and also main file added to the src folder. but when i compiler it shows a error that 'a.hpp:no such file or directory in function main()'. however i wrote a code to read header files from main file ( #include "a.hpp" ) and in my a.hpp, i wrote same code to call b.hpp file. 
i tried several ways but it shows same error message. so please help me to create a project with header files. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the prepocessor reads `#include "a.hpp"` it looks for `a.hpp` in the current folder. In your case, it means `src`. But your header files are not there ! They are in `C:/MyProjects/include`.

You need to tell the compiler where to look for include files. Usually it's something called "include directories" in the project options.

Comment: @mark and otibom: thank you very much for your answers, yes i got it, i changed my project options by including my folders into project. so now it is working....thanks for both of you for the nice work

Answer (score 2):

```
#include "../include/a.hpp"
```

or add that folder to project include path

Comment: Option 2 is infinitely better! :-)